# CNN not predicting class of image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have made a brain tumor detecting model using CNN, when I try to test a sample image by predicting it's class, an error occurs.

According to the error the input to the model should have 1 extra dimension. How do I predict the image's class. The code snippet that gives the error is:

```
best_model.predict(image)
```

The error is as follows

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer zero_padding2d is incompatible with the
> layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 240,
> 3]

The shape expected can be seen in the warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 240, 240, 3) for input Tensor("input_1_1:0", shape=(None, 240, 240, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 240, 3).
```

I tried the solution but it is still giving the same error:
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LlUn.png)

Comment: what is the shape of `image`? It seems that it's not a valid size to what the model is expecting

Comment: @David S The image is taken from the same, dataset that is used to train the model. The shape of the image is: (240,240,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that the model assume the first dimension is the number of batchs. In your case it "thinks" that you have 240 batches where each image in size `(240,3)`.

What you need to do is expand the dimensions of the image before passing to the model. you can use [`expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims)

an example:

```
image = tf.zeros([240, 240, 3])
tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
```

This will add a batch dimension to image, and the model can operate it properly.

Comment: @nanan I looked at the image you added to the question, you should do `image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)` Look at the doc, it returns a new expanded tensor